# How can I make the text completely not-editable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Current: The text in the text field is currently not editable, the backspace button does not delete any characters and right click to cut-copy-paste has been disabled. However, once I add some text to this existing not-editable text, I can use the arrow keys to move to through the characters and can delete some of them.

Target: I wish to make the not-editable text fixed such that I cannot use backspace, delete, cut-copy-paste with right click and most importantly, arrow keys to move to delete. I want this to be done using JQuery.

The code is as follows:

xhtml:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contenttitle').html($('.hiddenbred').html());
    $('.newsflash').css('display','none');  
    disableHalfText();
}
```

jsscript:
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.servicename').on("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
  });

```
function disableHalfText(){

var readOnlyLength = $('.servicename').val().length;

$('.servicename').on('keydown', function(event) {
    var $field = $(this);
    if ((event.which != 37 && (event.which != 39))
            && ((this.selectionStart < readOnlyLength)
                    || ((this.selectionStart == readOnlyLength) &&    (event.which == 8)))) {
        return false;
      }
   }); 
}
```

The output looks something like this:
Service name: TextNotEditable_addUserTextHere

My focus is on how i can disable any deletion after navigating using the arrow keys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: @Makaze I shall try that. Thank you!

Comment: you mean the user can not edit or delete the first part of text(`TextNotEditable_`) but can edit and delete second part(`addUserTextHere`)

Comment: The real question is why do you have a text field that doesn't allow text to be edited, this defeats the whole point of the text field

Comment: @WhoAmI yes that's right. the user cannot delete the first part of the text but can add, edit the second part

Comment: @Dmitri Well, this text value is carried forward from the previous page. So the user uses this to make a new service, keeping the old service name a part of the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your `<input>` element the property "disabled" and use the `user-select` CSS property (with prefixes for compatibility).
JQuery can toggle these things to achieve the desired result, e.g. when clicking a button to toggle the input box, as in:

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click tap', '#toggle-button', function() {
    var current = $(".input-toggle").prop("disabled"); // Get current state: disabled = true?

    $(".input-toggle")
        .prop("disabled", !current) // set to the opposite of the current state
        .toggleClass('no-select'); // don't let the user select!

});
```

CSS:

```
no-select {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[Example fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/onzr81y2/2/) - enjoy!

Comment: thank you so much! I hope this works well for me! :)